# Plane formed by three mutually perpendicular semi diameters of an ellipsoid.touches a fixed sphere

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry, ellipsoids

I have the following ellipsoid before me:
$(x^2/a^2)+(y^2/b^2)+(z^2/c^2)=1$.
There are three points $P$, $Q$ and $R$ on the ellipsoid which when joined with the origin form a set of three mutually perpendicular semi diameters of ellipsoid. I have to prove that plane formed by $P$ ,$Q$ and $R$ touches a fixed sphere.

I started off by assuming the equation of the plane $PQR$ as

$lx+my+nz=p$.
Three points $P$,$Q$ and $R$ were taken as $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3,z_3)$.
Thereafter I substituted the coordinates of three points in the equation of the plane to get three equations as below:
$lx_1+my_1+nz_1=p$;

$lx_2+my_2+nz_2=p$;

$lx_3+my_3+nz_3=p$

Multiplying first equation by $x_1$, second by $x_2$ and third by $x_3$, we get:

$l=p(x_1+x_2+x_3)/(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$.

We can get $m$ and $n$ wherein $x$ is replaced with $y$ and $z$ respectively.
After substituting these values of $l$ ,$m$ and $n$ in the equation of the plane, we get

$x(x_1+x_2+x_3)/(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+y(y_1+y_2+y_3)/(y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2)+z(z_1+z_2+z_3)/(z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2)= 1$.

Next I intend to find out the perpendicular distance of this plane from origin and see whether that comes out to be a constant.
But the equation of the plane seems quite daunting to me. And I am not able to simplify the expression of perpendicular distance to show that it is a constant quantity. Please suggest me how can I do that from here? Or is there any easier way out there? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $p = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we will abuse notation and use same symbol to denote corresponding $3\times 1$ column vector.

Let $\Lambda$ be the $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\frac1{a^2},\frac1{b^2},\frac1{c^2}$. In terms of column vectors,  the condition for a point $p$ to lie on the ellipse becomes $$p^T \Lambda p = 1$$

Let $n_1,n_2,n_3$ be any three unit vectors orthogonal to each other.
For each $k = 1,2,3$, construct a ray start at origin pointing along direction $n_k$. Let it intersect the ellipse at $\lambda_k n_k$. We have

$$(\lambda_k n_k)^T \Lambda (\lambda_k n_k) = 1 \quad\implies\quad
\frac1{\lambda_k^2} = n_k^T \Lambda n_k$$

Since the three unit vectors are orthogonal to each other, we can choose a Cartesian coordinate system having them as coordinate axes. In this new coordinate system (let's call the coordinates $(u, v, w)$), the equation of the plane becomes

$$\frac{u}{\lambda_1} + \frac{v}{\lambda_2} + \frac{w}{\lambda_3} = 1$$
and the distance $d$ between the plane and origin is given by formula:

$$d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac1{\lambda_1^2} + \frac1{\lambda_2^2} + \frac1{\lambda_3^2}}} \quad\iff\quad \frac{1}{d^2} = \frac1{\lambda_1^2} + \frac1{\lambda_2^2} + \frac1{\lambda_3^2}$$
In terms of $\Lambda$ and $n_k$, we have

$$\frac{1}{d^2} = \sum_{k=1}^3 n_k^T \Lambda n_k
= {\rm Tr}\left(\Lambda \sum_{k=1}^3 n_kn_k^T \right)$$

Notice $\sum\limits_{k=1}^3 n_k n_k^T = I_3$, the identity matrix. We have

$$\frac{1}{d^2} = {\rm Tr}(\Lambda) = \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}
$$

From this, we can conclude the distance $d$ is independent of explicit choices of $n_1,n_2,n_3$. As a result, all the planes so constructed are touching a fixed sphere centered at origin with radius $\frac{abc}{\sqrt{a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2}}$.

Comment: Is there any method whereby I can get to the answer from where I left off?

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT no idea. In general when you are doing analytic geometry. avoid writing out all equations and variables. it usually become so complicated and you will lost in the detail quickly. Instead, try to view individual pieces as object, manipulate its properties and discover relations among them. Sometimes mapping the object to matrices/vectors or complex number also help.